# Javascript calling Function() to create a function

Tags: javascript, function, native, deobfuscation

Can anyone explain the following code?

```
Function(
Function(
'return \'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\''
)  ()  
)()
```

Interesting here: an actual function is getting created using the `Function()`.

But since I cannot view the native code, I am having difficulty understanding the actual function that is getting created. This is taken from root-me.org Javascript - native code challenge.

Comment: What happens when you run this in the console? `Function(
'return \'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\''
)  ()  `

Comment: `a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}`

Answer (score 2):

It deobfuscates to:

```
a = prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');
if(a=='toto123lol'){
    alert('bravo');
} else{
    alert('fail...');
}
```

To verify, in Chrome, open Developer Tools, open the console, and paste in:

```
Function(
    'return \'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\''
)  ()
```

This is the steps of "how the encoding works", essentially.  To "encode" the letter "a":

```
test = "a";
console.log(test.charCodeAt(0)); //97
console.log(parseInt('141', 8)); //97
console.log('\141'); //a
```

Comment: how can we de-obfuscate the native code from OP to your answer :) ?

Comment: @Arkantos type it in chrome console? `'\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47.......'` quoted

Comment: Excellent. Wonderful! However one thing I am not yet getting is that what sort of encoding is this? And what is the Chrome console actually doing in order to de obfuscate this? I knew that the Chrome Console executes javascript... but here the Console is actually giving the deobfuscated code!!! How is this possible?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=445179 gives a chart of which code translates to which letter.  You basically just have a series of escaped characters - the console unescapes the characters.

Answer (score 1):

> But since I cannot view the native code, I am having difficulty understanding the actual function that is getting created.

You have native code inside the script tag. It just looks unusual as it is referencing the ASCII key codes; octagonal to be exact (OCT). Here is a link

[ASCII Key Codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

First we have an executable  tag that starts things off. Here is a link explaining what it does.

[HTML  tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Inside the  tag we have two functions or function constructors.

If your were to type Function() into your console you would get

```
function anonymous() {}
```

For more information check out this link.

[Funciton JS link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Let's start with the nested function first.

```
Function(
  'return \'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\'')()
```

By using the JS Function constructor, we can pass in arguments to our new function as well as the function body.

> new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)

In the nested function we just create an anonumous funciton and pass it a function body in the form of a string like this

```
'return \'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\''
```

When the function runs the first string '' (quotes) are removed and this statement is run

```
return \'\\141\\75...'
```

The return, of course executes and exits the function, and when THIS function is run we get another function body in the form of another string value.

```
"a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}"
```

The leading '\', which is after the return statement, but before the actual string is only to escape the following quote, so the compiler does not mistake it for the second closing quote of the quote just before the return statement. We could get rid of it, as well as the second one just after the last number, and instead write the function body like this

```
Function(
'return "\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175"')()
```

If you ran this code in your console you would get the same result, try it!

If you do you will find that all these numbers have compiled to actual letters and numbers, in fact it compiled to ASCII character codes. This happened because of the use of '\' which proceeds each number. For less confusion, let's turn this "\\" instead into this "\"

```
Function(
'return "\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\145\40\160\141\163\163\145\47\51\73\151\146\50\141\75\75\47\164\157\164\157\61\62\63\154\157\154\47\51\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\142\162\141\166\157\47\51\73\175\145\154\163\145\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\146\141\151\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\175"')()
```

As you will see, this will still run and we get

```
"a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}"
```

So the nested function returns a function body as a string, which then gets executed in the outer Function constructer in the same way that the nested function fired. Here is the same example with a few things removed for better clarity

```
 Function(
Function('return "\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\145\40\160\141\163\163\145\47\51\73\151\146\50\141\75\75\47\164\157\164\157\61\62\63\154\157\154\47\51\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\142\162\141\166\157\47\51\73\175\145\154\163\145\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\146\141\151\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\175"')())()
```

**Note:** you may need to open a new window and then paste this in the console and click enter.

And for even more clarity, we could just copy and paste the initial returned value into the outer function like this

```
Function("a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}")()
```

This will also work.

What the nested function does

The first part opens a browser prompt window and attaches its future value to variable 'a'. Try this

```
Function("a=prompt('Enter Password');console.log(a);")()
```

when you press enter your value will show in the console. The second part of the function analizes this returned value by comparing it to a string 'toto123lol'.

when the entered value is exactly 'toto123lol' a new alert window will appear displaying 'bravo'.

If the entered value is not exactly 'toto123lol' a new alert window will appear displaying 'fail...'

As you can see, the initial function of your question contains all the needed information to not only run working code, but also all the native code you need to figure out what it is doing.

After checkout out the website you mentioned

[Root-me.org](http://www.root-me.org/?lang=en)

Perhaps what the test is trying to show is that what may look like harmless code, can actually be anything with could be executable within an HTML  tag. Or perhaps that there are many ways in which to influence behavior?

I hope this answers your question.

**UPDATE:** If you are wondering what the difference is between '\\' or '\' I have asked it here - [why double or single escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549707/what-is-the-difference-between-a-single-and-double-escape-backslash-in-javascr)

Comment: Brilliant explanations. I love it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you say that it answered your question?

Comment: Of course. It did more than just answer my question.