# What is the difference between a single and double escape (backslash) in Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string, function, escaping, ascii

After attempting to answer the question to this post

[Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546865/javascript-calling-function-to-create-a-function)

I noted that this

```
Function('return "\\101\\40\\171\\145\\154\\154\\157\\167\\40\\142\\165\\164\\164\\157\\156\\56"')()
```

or

```
Function('return "\101\40\171\145\154\154\157\167\40\142\165\164\164\157\156\56"')()
```

both return the same string - "A yellow button."

In regards to the question I linked to above, the JS code snippet is run in a  tag.

I have also noted in the past that when working on some JSON strings, that the '\' was needed over '\'

When is it necessary?
Why is it necessary?
If it is not necessary, then why is it done?

Links and additional reading are helpful to me.

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps I did not ask this question with enough information.

I understand when and why escaping is needed.

What I would like to know are two things

In the link above, the code has two function; one nested in the other like so

```
Function(
  Function(
    'return\'\\141\\75\\160\\162\\157\\155\\160\\164\\50\\47\\105\\156\\164\\162\\145\\172\\40\\154\\145\\40\\155\\157\\164\\40\\144\\145\\40\\160\\141\\163\\163\\145\\47\\51\\73\\151\\146\\50\\141\\75\\75\\47\\164\\157\\164\\157\\61\\62\\63\\154\\157\\154\\47\\51\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\142\\162\\141\\166\\157\\47\\51\\73\\175\\145\\154\\163\\145\\173\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\47\\146\\141\\151\\154\\56\\56\\56\\47\\51\\73\\175\'')())()
```

This script works as well as this script

```
Function(
  Function('return "\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\145\40\160\141\163\163\145\47\51\73\151\146\50\141\75\75\47\164\157\164\157\61\62\63\154\157\154\47\51\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\142\162\141\166\157\47\51\73\175\145\154\163\145\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\146\141\151\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\175"')())()
```

Why, if both scripts work would the "\\" be needed over "\"? Is there something I am missing here?

The second question would be,

Are there fundamental occurances when "\\" would be required over "\"?

I think sventschui is getting there, but not quite yet.

Comment: Well, for some characters you will need the double escaping, most prominently `\ ` and `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [sventschui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549789/227299) has the right idea, let me try to explain it in a different way.

When you define a string using
 `str1='"\\101\\40\\171\\145\\154\\154\\157\\167\\40\\142\\165\\164\\164\\157\\156\\56"'`

The `\\` is the escape sequence and the actual string in memory is (including the quotes around it) `"\101\40\171\145\154\154\157\167\40\142\165\164\164\157\156\56"`

---

When you defined a string as `str2="\101\40\171\145\154\154\157\167\40\142\165\164\164\157\156\56"`

The `\101`,`\40`,... are the escape sequences and the actual string in memory is (including the quotes around it)`"A yellow button"`

---

When you create a `Function()`, it re-evaluates the strings (like `eval`), for the first case, `str1` now it treats the `\101`, `\40` as escape sequences, and the returned string is `A yellow button`, without the quotes around it.

When you do the same thing to the second string, there are no escape sequences, just regular characters, so the string is unchanged (except for the quotes around it)

```js
var str1 = '"\\101"'; // "\101"
var str2 = '"\101"'; //  "A"

var str1Evaled = eval(str1); // \101 is the escape sequence, outputs A
var str2Evaled = eval(str2); // No escape sequence, a raw A

console.log({str1, str2, str1Evaled, str2Evaled});

//  Object {str1: ""\101"", str2: ""A"", str1Evaled: "A", str2Evaled: "A"}
```

Comment: would there be any advantage to using double or single given the two functions in my updated question? Or would both cases just do the same thing?

Comment: I don't see an advantage of the first case, `\\101`, that is just confusing because you are combining two types of escaping. The `\\ ` is the standard  escape sequence, and `\101` is the octal escape. The advantage of octal, or hexadecimal is that you can encode all the characters, but it will take extra bytes. The `\'`,`\r`, `\n` are easier to read and usually are used when you hard code those values in your code. My suggestion, use a single type of escaping in a string for legibility purposes See http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml

Comment: I thought it was confusing as well, and perhaps not needed. However, I thought that perhaps I am missing something bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're nesting two strings both examples return the same string.

---

```
'return "\\101\\40\\171\\145\\154\\154\\157\\167\\40\\142\\165\\164\\164\\157\\156\\56"'
```

evaluates to

```
return "\101\40\171\145\154\154\157\167\40\142\165\164\164\157\156\56"
```

what evaluates to

```
A yellow button
```

---

```
'return "\101\40\171\145\154\154\157\167\40\142\165\164\164\157\156\56"'
```

evaluates to

```
return "A yellow button"
```

what evaluates to

```
A yellow button
```

---

**Edit:**

Double escaping is used because when \000 WOULD evaluate to \ the following example would mess up:

```
'return "\000\000"'
```

evaluates to

```
return "\\"
```

what evaluates to

```
\
```

---

```
'return "\\000\\000"'
```

evaluates to

```
return "\000\000"
```

what evaluates to

```
\\
```

Comment: Can you take a peak at the link I provided? If I nest the functions and user either single or double I still get the same result. I understand character escaping, I just didn't quite get why one would do this when single escapes still work. Also, both of the above functions return the same thing.

Comment: See my update on when double escaping is different from single escaping