# Regex involving curly braces not working, while for square brackets it does

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I have this regex that matches something like `[abc]` as a string pattern, with the help of
`"[]": "((\\[[^\\]]*($|\\]))(\\][^\\]]*($|\\]))*)`

So it will catch `[ABC]` from `ABC A B [ABC] BC`. So anything enclosed in a square bracket.

It works as it's supposed to.

Then I wrote an expression like
`"{{}}": "((\\{\\{[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}\\}))(\\}\\}[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}\\}))*)"`

to catch something like `{{abc}}`. Now, this does work in online regex testers, it catches `{{abc}}` from `ABC A B {{ABC}} BC`.

But it's not doing anything when I have it in a JS code. While, the square bracket expression does what it's supposed to. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem. I also tried to use your code and it seems to work:

```js
function createStringRegex(stringTypes) {
    return new RegExp('^(' + this.createStringPattern(stringTypes) + ')', 'u');
  }

// This enables the following string patterns:
// 1. backtick quoted string using `` to escape
// 2. square bracket quoted string (SQL Server) using ]] to escape
// 3. double quoted string using "" or \" to escape

function createStringPattern(stringTypes) {
  const patterns = {
    '``': '((`[^`]*($|`))+)',
    '[]': '((\\[[^\\]]*($|\\]))(\\][^\\]]*($|\\]))*)',
    "{{}}": "((\\{\\{[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}\\}))(\\}\\}[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}\\}))*)",
    '""': '(("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*("|$))+)',
    "''": "(('[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*('|$))+)",
    "N''": "((N'[^N'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^N'\\\\]*)*('|$))+)"
  };

  return stringTypes.map(t => patterns[t]).join('|');
}

console.log("[abc]".match(createStringRegex(["[]"])));     // it matches 
console.log("{{abc}}".match(createStringRegex(["{{}}"]))); // it matches
console.log("[abc]".match(createStringRegex(["{{}}"])));   // it doesn't match
```

Comment: The regex is taken inside another function and I'm following the format from the rest of the expressions, the case is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549707/what-is-the-difference-between-a-single-and-double-escape-backslash-in-javascr

Comment: Exactly! It seems to work otherwise. Just not in the JS file, where other expressions do  work.

Comment: @arpo To me it seems to work. Isn't this the expected behavior?

Comment: Expected behaviour indeed. Many thanks fr, realised what was missing.

Comment: if it's no bother, could you take a look at this?

`"{{}}": "((\\{\\{[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}+))(\\}\\}[^\\}\\}]*($|\\}\\}))*)"`

is this a good logic to capture something like {{{abc}}} or n number of enclosing braces on top of the regular {{abc}}?

Comment: @arpo It depends on what you would allow and deny, but it would require another question to be opened. What I can say is that `[^\\}\\}]` is just an equivalent (but redundant) way of expressing `[^\\}]`, since the character class construct (`[...]`) matches single characters, not strings.

Comment: oh okay, also, thanks for pointing that out!